# C++11 range for over "tuple"

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to implement a hash class using C++11 features. I'm not reusing stl's hash because it's a school assignment. I'm trying to do this:

```
for(auto &h : {H1[hash_func(n1, val)], H2[hash_func(n2, val)]}) {
    for(auto &x : h) {
        if(x == val) {
            swap(x, h.back());
            h.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
```

`H1` and `H2` are of type `vector<T>*`. When I try to compile this, I get a nasty syntax error I can't even make sense of. If I try `for(auto &h : {H1, H2})` and use `h[hash_func(n1, val)]` instead of `h`, it works (though it's obviously wrong). How can I fix this? (or at least implement it in a manner that's more elegant than writing the same thing twice)

Comment: [Looks](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3IrjlE$0) good for me, except for one - you can't change values in braced-init-lists.

Comment: @soon, could you please explain to me what this is line of code is doing? `std::vector<int>* v1 = new std::vector<int>[2]{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};`

Comment: @OGH, allocates memory for array of `std::vector`s and initializes vectors in the array

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could have an array of vectors.

Comment: @soon Odd. Why are you using  dynamic memory allocation here?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, you can increase the size of the array if you dynamically allocate it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Why not? We can use, of course, static arrays, however, no difference will be.

Comment: @soon this is interesting. What do you mean by "you can't change values in braced-init-lists"? I think this is the case with my code. Here's the complete code (with the compilation errors): http://liveworkspace.org/code/3IrjlE$8

Comment: @soon Because it’s unnecessarily complicated. You don’t need `static` either, just declare an array of vectors. You don’t use `int* i = new int[2];` instead of `int i[2];` either, do you?

Comment: @OGH Sure but then (in real code at least) you wouldn’t use manual memory management, you’d use a vector of vectors.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I agree with you, that using dynamically allocated arrays is complicated than static arrays. I know, that I don't need keyword static, of course. But when I wrote an example, I didn't think about "How to allocate array: dynamically or static?", because it doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: Another note. You can't modify (`pop_back`) the collection while you are iterating over it as it will invalidate the iterators. Google the remove-erase idiom instead.

Comment: @GabiPurcaru, I meant, that you can't change it :) All values in a `initializer_list` are constants.

Comment: @soon there is a huge difference in performance allocating arrays from the stack (automatic storage for local variables/parameters and class members) vs. allocating them from the heap. For short lived, single owner data, prefer automatic storage at all times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error messages you posted, the error is completely unrelated to this passage, and caused by the fact that you are trying to swap *`const`* `int`. The reason for that is that your `H1[…]` access in the initialiser list is *copying* the vectors, hence you end up with a temporary object which is implicitly bound to a `const` reference. As a consequence, the members of the vector are `const` as well.

It’s worse than that: even if you fix this error, your code won’t work because you are accessing the wrong type. Your members are initialised as follows:

```
H1 = new vector<T>[n];
```

`H1` is a pointer to a *single* vector. You almost certainly don’t want that since then in your code you access it with an index:

```
H1[hash_func(n1, val)]
```

If `hash_func` yields anything other than `0` your code accesses invalid memory.

Why are `H1` and `H2` pointers anyway? *Do not use manual memory management*. Just use plain vectors.

Comment: @Gabi See update. In fact, your code, if it compiled, would actually delete objects from a *copy* of the vectors, not the actual vectors. You can use `std::ref` to get a reference rather than a copy, but that won’t solve the second problem alluded to in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this by turning to pointers:

```
for(auto h : {&H1[hash_func(n1, val)], &H2[hash_func(n2, val)]}) {
    for(auto &x : *h) {
        if(x == val) {
            swap(x, h->back());
            h->pop_back();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```